# How to install php 5.3.2 on debian from the command line?

Tags: php, installation, debian

i want to upgrade my php version on debian from the command line.

Comment: this is Server Administartion related question ask here http://serverfault.com/  Satckoverflow is a place for programming related things only :) .

Answer (score 1):

As root type the following command:

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

This will update your repositories and then update every piece of software on your system. As long as PHP 5.2.3 is in your configured repositories it should upgrade.

If you dont have a repository that has PHP 5.3.2, you may be able to add one that includes this at: http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/